# Naming files for Adobe Times-Roman small caps

Tags: fonts

I want to install the genuine Adobe Times-Roman Small Caps and Times-Roman Bold Small Caps fonts for use with LaTeX. They were distributed by Adobe as `TIRSC___.PFB` and `TIBSC___.PFB`, respectively, along with the corresponding `.PFM` and `.AFM` files. My question is what names to use that would be consistent with the TeX font-naming standards. (This is before all the processing with `fontinst`.)

For Times-Roman Small Caps, is it correct to use `ptmrc8a`? That is, `p` for Adobe; `tm` for Times-Roman; `r` for Regular; `c` for small-caps (and `8a` for Adobe Standard Encoding)? Or instead of `r` should it be `m`, for medium weight?

For Times-Roman Bold Small Caps, should it then be `ptmbc8a`?  (Elsewhere, it was suggested that this should be `pfmb8a` -- see http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=20093. But I suspect that `f` there was a typo for `t`; and surely a `c` is needed after `b`?)

Comment: I agree with you. Test and check in your viewer if the real fonts are used.

Comment: @Bernard: Are you saying that the answer to each of my two questions should be "yes"?

Comment: Yes, si, ja, oui, ναι (! That makes the count: at least 15 characters in comments).

Comment: @Bernard You clearly need to learn Welsh. (Many, many words for 'yes' - more than enough for a comment. Of course, only one would be strictly correct...)

Comment: @cfr Ið, I've seen that —

Comment: @Bernard ;) What language is that?

Comment: One version of ‘yes’ in Cymric (= Welsh). Haven't you read the Mabinogion?

Answer (score 1):

see http://mirror.ctan.org/info/fontname/fontname.html

But nowadays one can choose any filename. It is no more a big problem.

Comment: But surely the name *would* be a problem if, say, I want to use `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` for specifying the font.

Comment: It is obvious that you shouldn't use an existing name. However, a name like `myptm` would be fine and no problem.

Comment: How would `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` recognize `myptm`?

Comment: @murray You **need** to use the existing name because you are going to want to integrate these 2 fonts (I assume) into an existing family. That is, you are going to want a new font definition file which sets up `ptm` in a particular encoding and which incorporates both existing fonts and these 2 new ones. Strictly speaking, you could call the actual fonts something else but there is no reason to do so and every reason not to.

Comment: The question is what you want to do? Do you want to modify the existing `t1ptm.fd` or do you want to create an own t1myptm.fd with a package `mytimes.sty`.

Comment: I'm putting all the new font files, including `fd`'s, into my local `texmf` tree (namely, `~/Library/texmf`) rather than into the system `texmf` tree created by TeXLive 2014. If I have anewly-created `fd` such as `t1ptm.fd` in my local tree, won't that be used rather than the system version? (And similarly for other font support files.)